# form wont submit with jquery form submit when some fields are disabled

Tags: jquery

I am submitting a form via jquery form submit. just like this [example](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples) 
However, I have given the user an option to disable some fields on the form. I am using following jquery code to do this:

```
   $('#onlyTwo').click(function(){
        var stuff = $("#textarea3,  #textarea4, #radio3, #radio4, #onlyThree");
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            stuff.attr("disabled", true);
        else {
            stuff.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```

basically, onlyTwo is a checkbox. on toggle some fields are made disabled.

The form does not seem to submit when some fields are made disabled.  There are 8 fields on the form and seems like each time i click submit it expects those 8 fields no matter what.

has someone encountered this before?

Complete Code:
code for ajax Form Submit

```
    var options = {
        target:        '#output1',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback
    };


    // bind form using 'ajaxForm'
        $('#addQuestionForm').ajaxForm(options);
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var queryString = $.param(formData);
    alert('data: ' + formData);
    return true;
}

// post-submit callback
function showResponse(responseText, statusText)  {
    $('#output1').slideDown(100);
    $('#output1').fadeOut(3500);
    $('#question').val('');
    $('#textarea1').val('');
    $('#textarea2').val('');
    $('#textarea3').val('');
    $('#textarea4').val('');
    $('#question').val('');
    $('input[name="correctAnswer"]').attr('checked', false);
}
```

code to disable fields:

```
    $('#onlyTwo').click(function(){
        var stuff = $("#textarea3,  #textarea4, #radio3, #radio4, #onlyThree");
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            stuff.attr("disabled", true);
        else {
            stuff.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

    $('#onlyThree').click(function(){
        var stuff = $("#textarea4, #radio4, #onlyTwo");
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            stuff.attr("disabled", true);
        else {
            stuff.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
```

code for my form:

```
            <s:form id="addQuestionForm" action="addQuestion" namespace="/securityExam" method="post">
                <table border="0">
                        <td>Question For</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="questionsType" id="questionsType">
                                <option selected="selected" value="U">Users</option>
                                <option value="C">Co-ordinators</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Question</td>
                        <td><textarea id="question" name="question" rows="3" cols="35"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Option 1</td>
                        <td><textarea  id="textarea1" name="option1" rows="3" cols="35"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Option 2</td>
                        <td><textarea  id="textarea2" name="option2" rows="3" cols="35"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Option 3</td>
                        <td><textarea id="textarea3" name="option3" rows="3" cols="35"></textarea></td>
                        <td><input id="onlyTwo" type="checkbox">Only two options</input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Option 4</td>
                        <td><textarea id="textarea4" name="option4" rows="3" cols="35"></textarea></td>
                        <td><input id="onlyThree" type="checkbox">Only three options</input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Correct Option</td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="correctAnswer" value="1">1</input>
                            <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="correctAnswer" value="2">2</input>
                            <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="correctAnswer" value="3">3</input>
                            <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="correctAnswer" value="4">4</input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br><br>
                 <s:submit name="Submit"/>
            </s:form>
```

Comment: Don't see anything wrong here, maybe if you show more code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Try this (if you are clicking #onlyTwo or #onlyThree twice I think they both must be "unchecked")

```
function ClearAllStuff() {
    $("#textarea3,  #textarea4, #radio3, #radio4, #onlyThree, #onlyTwo").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#onlyThree, #onlyTwo").removeAttr("checked");
}

$('#onlyTwo').click(function(){
    var stuff = $("#textarea3,  #textarea4, #radio3, #radio4, #onlyThree");
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        stuff.attr("disabled", true);
    else {
        ClearAllStuff();
    }
});

$('#onlyThree').click(function(){
    var stuff = $("#textarea4, #radio4, #onlyTwo");
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        stuff.attr("disabled", true);
    else {
        ClearAllStuff();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[According to the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) disabled form fields cannot be submitted because they are not "successful." Basically, they don't go along for the ride when your form's submitted by design.

You can try to bind a function to your form's submit Event to re-enable all of those disabled boxes and make them "successful" and submitted (and set them to a sensible default value so you know that your user disabled them and not just left them blank, etc.).

[**EDIT:** This was based on the original post before the OP made a couple edits, so YMMV.]

```
$('#yourForm').bind('submit',function(){
    $(this).find(':disabled').removeAttr('disabled').val('disabledByUser');
    return true;
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this code you're posting is wrapped inside a `$(document).ready(function() { });` or `$.ready(function () { });` that you just didn't include in the example right?

**Right?**

Comment: Just making sure!  Weird things like this happen if you don't!